# Add search to extended toolbar

Tags: android

I want to have a search bar like this...

[image]

I only have the blue toolbar without the search

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:title="Messages"
android:titleTextColor="@color/bg_screen3"
android:background="@color/bg_screen3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="112dp"
android:gravity="center" />
```

How do I add the search placed in that position.?

Comment: First, where did you get that image? An actual android app? Status bar looks like iPhone... Second, It's definitely a custom drawable, not a built-in search bar

Comment: @cricket_007  I've changed the image...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can use Material Searchview

```
<!— Must be last for right layering display —>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

Comment: That's an expandable search. I need a persistent search because search is the primary focus of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required design by using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
    android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showSearch"
    app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search..."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The final outcome is like this. I used the FloatingSearchView library to get the persistent search view.

[image]

You can also declare the height of the toolbar to make it extend from the default height. With a height of 128dp( 56dp + 72dp as defined in Android specs), the outcome is like this:
[image]